# Shared microservice, Micronaut error - Multiple possible bean candidates found

Tags: dependency-injection, shared-libraries, micronaut, micronaut-data

I am trying to build a simple API using Micronaut to fetch all users, which works properly on localhost, but facing the below issue with docker image -

> Internal Server Error: Error instantiating bean of type  [com.cawstudios.authentication_service.controllers.UserController]\n\nMessage: Multiple possible bean candidates found: [io.micronaut.aop.InterceptorRegistry, io.micronaut.aop.InterceptorRegistry]\nPath Taken: new UserController(UserRepository userRepository) --> new UserController([UserRepository userRepository]

Structure -

```
Authentication-service
 - Controllers
   - UserController
 - Reposotories
   - UserRepository

Common 
 - Entities
   UserEntity
```

I have a requirement to use 1 DB across multiple microservices.
Common is a shared service where I am trying to put all the entities so that any microservice can use them by adding common as their dependency.

UserController

```
import com.cawstudios.authentication_service.repositories.UserRepository;

import com.cawstudios.common.entities.UserEntity;
import io.micronaut.http.HttpResponse;
import io.micronaut.http.MediaType;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get;

import java.util.List;

@Controller("/users")
public class UserController {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserController(final UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Get("/")
    public HttpResponse<List<UserEntity>> getUsers() {
        List<UserEntity> userModels = this.userRepository.findAll();
        return HttpResponse.ok(userModels);
    }
```

UserRepository

```
import com.cawstudios.common.entities.UserEntity;
import io.micronaut.data.annotation.Repository;
import io.micronaut.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<UserEntity, UUID> {
    @Override
    List<UserEntity> findAll();
}
```

Pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.cawstudios</groupId>
  <artifactId>authentication-service</artifactId>
  <version>0.1</version>
  <packaging>${packaging}</packaging>

  <parent>
    <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
    <artifactId>micronaut-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
    <relativePath/>
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <jdk.version>11</jdk.version>
    <release.version>11</release.version>
    <micronaut.version>3.4.0</micronaut.version>
    <exec.mainClass>com.cawstudios.authentication_service.Application</exec.mainClass>
    <micronaut.runtime>netty</micronaut.runtime>
    <org.mapstruct.version>1.5.0.RC1</org.mapstruct.version>
    <org.projectlombok.version>1.18.22</org.projectlombok.version>
    <micronaut.data.version>3.2.1</micronaut.data.version>
    </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-inject</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.test</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-test-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-http-client</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-http-server-netty</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-runtime</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--  Logging  -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--  DB  -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-data-hibernate-jpa</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.sql</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-jdbc-hikari</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--  Lombok  -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>${org.projectlombok.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--  Supply chain service dependency  -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.cawstudios</groupId>
          <artifactId>common</artifactId>
          <version>0.1</version>
          <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>

<!--  Mapper  -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
      <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
      <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
      <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
      <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>

    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.micronaut.build</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <!-- Uncomment to enable incremental compilation -->
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
          <annotationProcessorPaths combine.children="append">
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-http-validation</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
            </path>

            <!--   DB   -->
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-data-processor</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.data.version}</version>
            </path>

            <!--  Lombok  -->
            <path>
              <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
              <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
              <version>${org.projectlombok.version}</version>
            </path>
            <!-- Dependency Injection -->
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-inject-java</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
            </path>

            <!--  Mapper  -->
            <path>
              <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
              <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
              <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
              <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
              <version>0.1.0</version>
            </path>

          </annotationProcessorPaths>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.group=com.cawstudios</arg>
            <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.module=authentication-service</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

UserEntity

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false)
    private String username;

    private String email;

    @Column(name = "gitToken", nullable = false)
    private String gitToken;
}
```

Comment: Updated my question, above error only appears when I try to use shared microservices.

Comment: Upgrading micronaut to latest version ( which currently at this time is 3.6.2 ) fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a dependency on a shaded/shadowed jar